# SCSS Background Image URL Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I've been trying to reference a image in my scss file by passing the code:

```
background-image: asset-url("bg.jpg", image) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

I've also tried:

```
background-image: image-url("bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
```

However when I run rails s I get the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/bg.jpg"):
```

And yes, I'm certain that my image is on app/assets/images.

How can I manage to solve this problem?

View File (Downloaded from Startup Bootstrap):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Stylish Portfolio Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap", "custom" %>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Side Menu -->
    <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <a id="menu-close" href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg pull-right toggle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#top">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /Side Menu -->

    <!-- Full Page Image Header Area -->
    <div id="top" class="header">
        <div class="vert-text">
            <h1>Start Bootstrap</h1>
            <h3>
                <em>We</em> Build Great Templates,
                <em>You</em> Make Them Better</h3>
            <a href="#about" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Find Out More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Full Page Image Header Area -->

    <!-- Intro -->
    <div id="about" class="intro">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
                    <h2>Subtle Sidebar is the Perfect Template for your Next Portfolio Website Project!</h2>
                    <p class="lead">This template really has it all. It's up to you to customize it to your liking! It features some fresh photography courtesy of <a target="_blank" href="http://join.deathtothestockphoto.com/">Death to the Stock Photo</a>.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Intro -->

    <!-- Services -->
    <div id="services" class="services">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
                    <h2>Our Services</h2>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                    <div class="service-item">
                        <i class="service-icon fa fa-rocket"></i>
                        <h4>Spacecraft Repair</h4>
                        <p>Did your navigation system shut down in the middle of that asteroid field? We can repair any dings and scrapes to your spacecraft!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                    <div class="service-item">
                        <i class="service-icon fa fa-magnet"></i>
                        <h4>Problem Solving</h4>
                        <p>Need to know how magnets work? Our problem solving solutions team can help you identify problems and conduct exploratory research.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                    <div class="service-item">
                        <i class="service-icon fa fa-shield"></i>
                        <h4>Blacksmithing</h4>
                        <p>Planning a time travel trip to the middle ages? Preserve the space time continuum by blending in with period accurate armor and weapons.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                    <div class="service-item">
                        <i class="service-icon fa fa-pencil"></i>
                        <h4>Pencil Sharpening</h4>
                        <p>We've been voted the best pencil sharpening service for 10 consecutive years. If you have a pencil that feels dull, we'll get it sharp!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Services -->

    <!-- Callout -->
    <div class="callout">
        <div class="vert-text">
            <h1>A Dramatic Text Area</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Callout -->

    <!-- Portfolio -->
    <div id="portfolio" class="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
                    <h2>Our Work</h2>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                        <%= image_tag "portfolio-1.jpg" %>
                        <h4>Cityscape</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                        <%= image_tag "portfolio-2.jpg" %>
                        <h4>Is That On Fire?</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                        <%= image_tag "portfolio-3.jpg" %>
                        <h4>Stop Sign</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                        <%= image_tag "portfolio-4.jpg" %>
                        <h4>Narrow Focus</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Portfolio -->

    <!-- Call to Action -->
    <div class="call-to-action">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
                    <h3>The buttons below are impossible to resist.</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Click Me!</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Look at Me!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Call to Action -->

    <!-- Map -->
    <div id="contact" class="map">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=twitter&amp;sll=28.659344,-81.187888&amp;sspn=0.128789,0.264187&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
        <br />
        <small>
            <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=twitter&amp;sll=28.659344,-81.187888&amp;sspn=0.128789,0.264187&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A"></a>
        </small>
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <!-- /Map -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x"></i>
                        </li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></i>
                        </li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-dribbble fa-3x"></i>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="top-scroll">
                        <a href="#top"><i class="fa fa-circle-arrow-up scroll fa-4x"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Company 2013</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- /Footer -->

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.10.2.js" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap.js" %>

    <!-- Custom JavaScript for the Side Menu and Smooth Scrolling -->
    <script>
    $("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS File:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.vert-text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.vert-text h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

/* Side Menu */

#sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-right: -250px;
  right: 0;
  width: 250px;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  line-height: 40px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  color: #999999;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

#menu-toggle {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

#sidebar-wrapper.active {
  right: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.toggle {
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

/* Full Page Image Header Area */

.header {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-image: image-url("bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Intro */

.intro {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

/* Services */

.services {
  background: #7fbbda;
  padding: 50px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.service-item {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

i.service-icon {
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 56px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  line-height: 136px;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: center;
}

/* Callout */

.callout {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: table;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: image-url("callout.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Portfolio */

.portfolio {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.portfolio-item {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.img-portfolio {
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Call to Action */

.call-to-action {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #0a5175;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.call-to-action .btn {
  margin: 10px;
}

/* Map */

.map {
  height: 500px;
}

/* Footer */

footer {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.top-scroll {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.top-scroll a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

i.scroll {
  color: #333333;
}

i.scroll:hover {
  color: #0a5175;
}
/* Responsive */

@media (max-width: 768px) {

  .header {
  background-image: image-url("bg.jpg") no-repeat center center scroll; 
  }

  .callout {
  background-image: image-url("callout.jpg") no-repeat center center scroll;
  }

  .map {
  height: 75%;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` to precompile yours assets. `image-url("bg.jpg")` literally becomes `url(/assets/bg.jpg)`, which would yield a broken link in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm not getting the route error anymore, however the images are not showing on the page.

Comment: Post your view code, verify that the image is in public/assets/, and verify that the correct styles are being applied.

Comment: Yes the image is there: bg-fd2fe4f799427986ffb2179f8b49467f. I'll edit the question to include my view

Comment: You shouldn't have to run `rake assets:precompile` to view the assets in development.  That's only something that should be required in a production environment.  Remove the "public/assets" folder and then check your site's "/assets/bg.jpg" and "/assets/images/bg.jpg" to see if either of those shows the image you're expecting (in the browser)

Comment: I've tried placing the image on /assets/bg.jpg and /assets/images/bg.jpg and both are not working

Comment: @Leo Costa If you put the file into `app/assets/images/bg.jpg` then it should be available at the route `http://www.mysite.com/assets/bg.jpg`.  Have you tried going to this in your browser?  (replacing 'mysite.com' with 'localhost' or '0.0.0.0' or whatever you have it running at locally of course).

Comment: nzifnab Thanks for all the help, I was able to solve the problem. For some reason I needed to @import my css file in my application.css

Comment: You shouldn't use @import for your own stylesheets. Use something like `/*
*= require my_stylesheet_name
*/`